# Will multiple func.count().filter() scan DB more than once?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, aggregate-functions

I am developing an web application using pyramid web framework. I am using sqlalchemy for ORM and models. I am using postgres for DB.

Here is my query to fetch the various counts of the applications submitted by all users:

```
counts = dbsession.query(
    func.count(Application.id).filter(Application.state == state1),
    func.count(Application.id).filter(Application.state == state2),
    func.count(Application.id).filter(Application.state == state3)).first()
```

My doubts is whether this would scan DB multiple times which is not desirable.

Here is the generated sql:

```
 SELECT count(applications.id) 
 FILTER (WHERE applications.state = %(state_1)s) AS anon_1, count(applications.id) 
 FILTER (WHERE applications.state = %(state_2)s) AS anon_2, count(applications.id) 
 FILTER (WHERE applications.state = %(state_3)s) AS anon_3 
 FROM applications 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, it scans it only once, I suggest looking in to the `FILTER` keyword which works very similar to a `CASE WHEN` statement

Comment: Are you sure that it scans only once?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to inspect the query plan, if unsure.

Comment: hi @IljaEverilä. I used EXPLAIN and it printed this:  
[('Aggregate  (cost=962.93..962.94 rows=1 width=24)',), 
  ('  ->  Seq Scan on applications  (cost=0.00..650.97 rows=20797 width=8)',)]
What does this mean?

Comment: The query performs a single seq scan on applications, and then the aggregates. If you'll read on how `FILTER` works, it'll be clear why; `FILTER` simply restricts which rows of a group are fed to an aggregate, so there's no point in scanning the table multiple times.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Ok, thanks.